# Nested Attributes File Uploads - Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a Release model with tracks accepted as nested attributes. Before I embark on what might be an impossible task, does anyone know if it's possible to add a file attachement/upload with paperclip (or similar) so that I can add an audio file for each track on a release?

Comment: Yes you can, with Paperclip it works just like any other nested attribute.

Comment: Nice, i'll give it a go then!

Comment: Have a look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851013/nested-form-using-paperclip