# Association between two models rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

This should be somewhat simple but cant seem to grasp the association.

I am using nested_form and paperclip. I have a model called photo to store all images and a post model. I am trying to show the photos associated to the relevant post but am getting 'undefined method avatar' when rendering the view.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
attr_accessible :title, :comments, :photo_id, :avatar, :photos_attributes
end

Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
attr_accessible :avatar, :post_id
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Controller

```
def new
@post = Post.new
@post.photos.build
end
```

So i am under the impression that when a post gets built an association between the Post and Photo model is made? is that right?

So when i call this in the view i get the undefined method, can anyone advise where I am going wrong please

```
<% @posts.each do |f| %>
<ul>
 <li><%= f.title %></li>
 <li><%= f.department.name %></li>
 <li><%= image_tag f.avatar.url(:thumb) %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Delete Post", post_path(f.id), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

I have tried

```
<%= image_tag f.photo.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are creating photo wrong.

Here you can see how the form looks: [Nested form using paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851013/nested-form-using-paperclip)

And also `Post` `has_many :photos`, so it must be somth. like

```
<% @posts.each do |f| %>
....


 <% f.photos.each do |photo| %>
   <%= image_tag photo.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
 <% end %>


...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess it was building the photos as i changed my view for the photos to your answer, f.photos.each. So this works because the photos are nested within the posts? thanks though as all working and can now upload multiple images and display them relevant to their post

Comment: It works because your post has many photos. it means that ```f.photos``` returns an Array of ```Photo``` objects. So looping through them will show you images)

Answer (score 1):

When I work with nested attributes I follow three steps. First, in the parent model you can use accepts_nested_attributes_for:

```
Class Post
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  attr_accessible :photos_attributes
end
```

Second, you can incorporate a nested form for photos so you can set the attributes of photos for that particular post:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
  ...rest of form here...
```

Third, you can create a photo through the new action in the post model:

```
Class UserController
  def new
    @user = User.new(photos: Photo.new)
  end
end
```

This last step is important. If you don't do this, you would not see the photo fields in the user form otherwise. If you follow these steps you should be able to set all the attributes from both photos and users in the users form.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your controller you should first define which is the `post` object you are associating to :

```
 def new
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
   @photo = @post.photos.build

  ....
  end
```

The same is in the `create` action of the `PhotosController` .